# Create sequential ID column type when loading GeoDataFrame to PostGIS

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, pandas

Is there a way to define GID column as sequential (auto-incremental) when loading GeoDataFrame (created from Shapefile) to PostGIS?
I use Geopandas and "to_sql" method:

```
geodataframe.to_sql(tablename, engine, if_exists='fail', index=False, dtype={'gid':INTEGER(), 'user_name':Text, 'sessions':Text, 'geom':Geometry('MULTILINESTRING', srid=4326)})
```

I could not find any valid SQLAlchemy data type. It seems that none exists. Other option I see is: do not load GID column but create it after uploading data to PostGIS.